# Efficient Method To Partition MySQL Table By Year and Month

Tags: mysql, partitioning

I am exploring ways of partitioning a MySQL table by year and month. Can you please analyze my table creation below and see if this method of partitioning would end up putting data by month and year in these sub partitions? I'm using MySQL 5.5 and I can't use

```
SELECT * FROM points_log PARTITION (p0_p0sp0);
```

to validate if the partitioning is working. If there is a way to validate this in MySQL 5.5 please comment. I appreciate your feedback and criticisms on this table partitioning.

Here is my table creation:

```
CREATE TABLE `points_log` (
  `id` mediumint(8) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `nick` char(25) NOT NULL,
  `amount` decimal(7,4) NOT NULL,
  `stream_online` tinyint(1) NOT NULL,
  `modification_type` tinyint(3) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `dt` datetime NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`,`dt`,`nick`),
  KEY `nick_idx` (`nick`),
  KEY `amount_idx` (`amount`),
  KEY `modification_type_idx` (`modification_type`),
  KEY `dt_idx` (`dt`),
  KEY `stream_online_idx` (`stream_online`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=13 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1
  PARTITION BY RANGE( YEAR(dt) )
  SUBPARTITION BY HASH( MONTH(dt) )
  SUBPARTITIONS 12 (
      PARTITION p0 VALUES LESS THAN (2014),
      PARTITION p1 VALUES LESS THAN (2015),
      PARTITION p2 VALUES LESS THAN (2016),
      PARTITION p3 VALUES LESS THAN (2017),
      PARTITION p4 VALUES LESS THAN (2018),
      PARTITION p5 VALUES LESS THAN (2019),
      PARTITION p6 VALUES LESS THAN (2020),
      PARTITION p7 VALUES LESS THAN MAXVALUE
   );
```

Answer (score 25):

- `SUBPARTITIONs` are probably useless.  (That is, I have yet to find any advantage to their use.  That especially applies to performance.)
- Don't split the date; keep it as a single field.
- Use `BY RANGE(TO_DAYS(dt)) VALUES LESS THAN (TO_DAYS('2015-02-01'))`
- `BY HASH` is probably totally useless for performance.
- `WHERE dt BETWEEN .. AND ..` cannot do partition pruning in the structure you have.
- Do not use more than about 50 partitions (for performance reasons).
- Do not create more than one 'future' partition; build them as needed.  (This is a minor performance improvement.)
- Do not use `CHAR` for variable length fields.  Use `VARCHAR`.

Comment: I really don't know why you haven't received upvote. This is all true IMHO.

Comment: Thanks @seven; I have been ranting in this way for a long time; maybe others are simply rolling their eyes at my repetition.  You do have a point -- the Question has been 'viewed' 1171 times.

Comment: You are the author of the [PARTITION Maintenance](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/partitionmaint)! Thank you for keeping up this article. Please enjoy a cup of banana latte.

Comment: @dgregory - yum, yum.  Thanks.

Comment: what exactly makes subpartitions useless? These baseless sweeping claims are  very damaging.

Comment: @Mordechai - I would be glad to see an example of where `SUBPARTITIONs` provide any performance or other utility.  (I edited my claim.)

Comment: @RickJames I'm not sure how to respond. I've seen your write-up on partition maintenance, so obviously you don't need an introduction to the subject. Yet, you seem to question usability of being able to create more partitions using an additional criteria (hash or key).

Comment: @Mordechai - "Being able to create more partitions ..." -- My claim is "partitions (and subpartitions) are [in most cases] useless".  I realize it is a brash statement; but I stand by it -- after a decade of looking for counterexamples.

Comment: @RickJames can you explain why `WHERE dt BETWEEN .. AND ..` cannot do partition pruning in the structure above

Comment: @ChinhNguyen - Let me soften my statement.  `PARTITION BY HASH`, when given a range, does not go to the effort to figure out which partitions might need to be pruned.  Instead, it simply checks all partitions.  Meanwhile, when given a single value, it does do pruning.  But that is no faster than having an index that starts with the key.

Comment: @RickJames mysql `RANGE COLUMNS partitioning` support `DATETIME`, is that any faster your `RANGE` and `TO_DAYS`

Comment: @ChinhNguyen - Probably identical in performance, but `RANGE COLUMNS` is arguably cleaner in syntax.

Comment: I have been wondering about this (partition by month+year) as I have a database that must retain 7 years of data (~12 million records atm / ~800GB).  We archive and drop 1 month of data per month.  Would be really nice to just drop/truncate that partition and create a new one.

Comment: @KrisOye - For a sliding time range, yes, `DROP` the oldest and `REORGANIZE` to get a new partition.  See my link mentioned above.  Either have about 85 monthly partitions or 8 yearly partitions.   (That is also discussed in the link.)